# Sumarle dias a una fecha entrada por teclado

Tags: c++, poo, clase, sobrecarga-de-operadores, sobrecarga

Tengo una clase Fecha con su parte pública y privada y lo que tengo que hacer es sobrecargar el operador "+" de la siguiente manera: Fecha operator+(const int& dia) const. Lo que se me pide es que le sume un numero de dias pasado por parámetro a una fecha. Alguna idea?
Esta es la clase:

```
class Fecha
{
public:
    Fecha() { m_dia = 0; m_mes = 0; m_año = 0; }
    Fecha(int dia, int mes, int año) : m_dia(dia), m_mes(mes), m_año(año) { }
    void setDia(int dia) { m_dia = dia; }
    void setMes(int mes) { m_mes = mes; }
    void setAño(int año) { m_año = año; }
    int getDia() const { return m_dia; }
    int getMes() const { return m_mes; }
    int getAño() const { return m_año; }
    bool operator==(const Fecha& d2) const;
    Fecha operator+(const int& dia) const;
    bool operator <(const Fecha& d2) const;
    friend istream& operator>>(Fecha& d, istream& input);
    friend ostream& operator<<(Fecha& d, ostream& output);
private:
    int m_dia, m_mes, m_año;
    static const int N_MESES = 12;
    const int nDiesMes[N_MESES] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
};
```

Comment: Sumas los días que te den a la variable `m_dia`, despues compruebas si supera el número de días del mes, si es así, restas los días que toquen y le sumas uno al mes. Repites este paso hasta que el número de días no supere el máximo del mes. Después miras los meses, si superan los 12 sumas un año y restas 12 meses ... y repites hasta que la fecha sea válida

Comment: Por cierto, no se obtiene absolutamente ninguna ventaja pasando un entero como referencia constante ... de hecho el código será más ineficiente por tener que gestionar una referencia totalmente innecesaria

Comment: Es verdad ahora lo pruebo! Pero entonces me recomiendas pasar el entero sin referencia?                        Muchas gracias!

Comment: los tipos nativos entran en un registro del sistema, copiar su valor cuesta lo mismo que copiar su dirección de memoria... y te estás ahorrando la indirección. Sí, yo eliminaría la referencia

Comment: Entiendo, muchas gracias por la ayuda!